# Reverse proxy with IIS

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I'm trying to integrate ASP.net and Node.js on a server.

**My expectation is here.**

```
client ----> IIS Server     ----> ASP.NET (except /api/.  localhost:80)
            (test.foo.com)  |---> Node.js (starting with /api/. localhost:4000)
```

Node app is executed as a windows service, and serve localhost:4000/api/ in locally.  And should be accessed with `http://test.foo.com/api/signin`
All request excepting `/api/` should be served normal IIS asp.net. (ex. `http://test.foo.com/index.aspx`)

**My trial:**
 - Installed urlrewrite module and application request routing cache module.
 - Added rewriting rule as below

```
pattern: /api/(.*)
URL rewrite : http://localhost:4000/api/{R:1}
```

**My result:**
 - `http://test.foo.com/api/signin` returned as `503 Service Unavaile`

**Question:**
 - Using `URLrewrite` is the right solution for my case?

**Append**
I tried to with 127.0.0.1 instead localhost with below web.config setting.
That result was same "503".

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="/api/(.*)" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="http://127.0.0.1:4000/api/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
    <outboundRules>
        <rule name="ReverseProxyOutboundRule1" preCondition="ResponseIsHtml1">
            <match filterByTags="A, Form, Img" pattern="^http(s)?://127.0.0.1/(.*)" />
            <action type="Rewrite" value="http{R:1}://127.0.0.1:4000/{R:2}" />
        </rule>
        <preConditions>
            <preCondition name="ResponseIsHtml1">
                <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
            </preCondition>
        </preConditions>
    </outboundRules>
</rewrite>
```

**Append again**
Instead loop adapter, change to ipv4 address.  And tried to access anther PC.  But result was same.

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="http://192.168.123.12:4000/api/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
    <outboundRules>
        <rule name="ReverseProxyOutboundRule1" preCondition="ResponseIsHtml1">
            <match filterByTags="A, Form, Img" pattern="^http(s)?://192.168.123.12:4000/api/(.*)" />
            <action type="Rewrite" value="http{R:1}://192.168.123.12/{R:2}" />
        </rule>
        <preConditions>
            <preCondition name="ResponseIsHtml1">
                <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
            </preCondition>
        </preConditions>
    </outboundRules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Q: Do you still get "HTTP 503: service unavailable" with the URL `http://localhost:4000/api/signin`?  With the URL `http://test.foo.com:4000/api/signin`?

Comment: Both two URLs are works well.  These returns 200 OK.  But http://test.foo.com/api/signin returns 503.

Comment: OK.  Then change your re-write rule to the *HOSTNAME* (instead of "localhost").  Please let us know if that works.  Also, this links might help: [mod_rewrite: technical details](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/tech.html) and [When not to use mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/avoid.html).

Comment: I changed hostname to 127.0.0.1 instead localhost because I test it in my local PC now.  as `http://127.0.0.1:4000/api/{R:1}` Result is same.  As my guessing my rule was incorrect.

Comment: Merely URL Rewrite is not enough for reverse proxy. You should use ARR, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/planning-for-arr/using-the-application-request-routing-module

Comment: Your "rule" is just fine.  The problem is "redirecting" to localhost!  Don't do it!  Use a valid hostname or IP address (and NOT the loopback address!).  And do read the links I cited.  And Lex Li is correct - if you really want a "reverse proxy", URL re-write alone is probably not your best choice.

Comment: @LexLi   I'll try ARR.  BTW, I'm a fan of JexusManger.  Thanks for your advice and your JexusManager.

Comment: @paulsm4  It caused by my lack-understanding to reverse proxy.  Thanks for your help.  I should make effort to understand rewrite and reverse proxy.